# How to safely escape quotes in R to submit text to SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have some strings in `R` which should be written into a `MySQL` table using `RODBC`. 
The problem is that I do not know **how to handle quotes within the strings to get no MySQL errors but to also not mess up the text?**

I am sure the solution is kind of simple but at the moment I am kind of stuck in my own thinking - I do not get out of the box ... escaping not escaping escaping twice with 2 backslashes or better 4 (or 8, just to be on the save side)

**example:**

```
require(RODBC)
con     <- odbcConnect("MyMySQLDatabase")

string  <- "What's up?"
query   <- "INSERT INTO table (textcolumn) VALUES"

value   <- paste0( "('", string, "')" )
sql     <- paste( query, value, ";")

res     <- sqlQuery(con, sql)
```

(How to handle text that I read in from files with possible single and double quotes?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start by doubling quotes:

```
string <- gsub("'","''",string)
```

This will double the quotes:

```
string
[1] "What''s up?"
```

Comment: I think I do not get it: Would that not be like replacing all single quotes by "bubblediboo" or deleting them all together? I really want to preserve the text as-is.

Comment: @marvin_dpr you just add this line to your code and it will work.

Comment: ok, the answer to *Why does it work* comes from the SQL side of the problem. SQL actually offers a helping hand to problems like this and understands `''` explicitly as escaped `'` .

Answer (score 8):

**If one is using `RMySQL`** the **`dbEscapeStrings()`** function provided by the package is probably the best way to go. The function takes care of escaping adhering to the standards set by MySQL. [LINK](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/RMySQL.pdf)

```
require(RMySQL)
mysql   <- dbDriver("MySQL")
con     <- dbConnect( mysql, user="superuser", 
                password="totallyawesomeandsavepassword", 
                host="dbhost.hosthome.dom",
                dbname="awesome" 
                )
dbEscapeStrings(con,"'''''fhf'''''''''rh'''''''''")

# [1] "\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'fhf\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'rh\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'"
```

`RMySQL`'s manual states that:

> dbEscapeStrings Currently, only the MySQL driver implements this method

Comment: Not used in RMariaDB. `dbEscapeStrings()` has been deprecated. Please use `dbQuoteString()` instead

Comment: `dbQuoteString()` is working for me. It's a little cumbersome to pass the connection object every time I need to sanitize a string, but I'm assuming this is necessary so `DBI` can determine which escape character to use for different flavors of SQL.